# Subtrair uma hora do horário Atual

Tags: php

Como faco para subtrair uma hora exemplo recebo a hora assim:

```
<?php
$hora = "00:12:00"
eco $hora;
?>
```

Como faço para ficar assim :

```
11:12:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar o método `sub` para subtrair um intervalo usando o `DateInterval` no qual `PT1H` representa 1 hora. Veja:

```
$date = new DateTime('00:12:00');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo $date->format('h:i:s') . "\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/X6idx6).

Answer (score 2):

```
$hora = "00:12:00";
echo date("g:i:s", srttotime("-1 Hour", strtotime($hora)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio eu que essa não seja a forma adequada de se fazer isso, mas criei essa função para tal ação:

```
    <?php
    function menosUmaHora($string) {
        $hora = explode(':', $string);//Cria uma array com 3 posições: 0 hora, 1 minuto, 2 segundo
        $hora[0] = (int) $hora[0]; //converte de string para inteiro
        $hora[1] = (int) $hora[1]; //converte de string para inteiro
        $hora[2] = (int) $hora[2]; //converte de string para inteiro
        if ($hora[0] <= 0) { //Verifica se o valor da posição hora é menor ou igual a 0
            $hora[0] = 11; //Se sim, posição hora agora é 11
        } else {
            $hora[0] --; //Se não, posição hora terá 1 subtraido
        }
        return implode(':', $hora);//Monta a string em ordem hh:mm:ss e retorna
    }

    $string = "00:12:00";
    echo "Old hour: " . $string . '<br>';
    echo "New hour: " . menosUmaHora($string);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Retorna uma hora antes da data e hora atual.

```
date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime('-1 hour', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
```